# How to create string variable using array

Tags: arrays, for-loop

My array is like that.

```
arr [name, location, village, school, discription, asdsa, nssad]
```

I want to create string variable like that

```
String val = "name VARCHAR(200) DEFAULT NULL, location VARCHAR(202) DEFAULT NULL, village VARCHAR(200) DEFAULT NULL, school VARCHAR(200) DEFAULT NULL, discription VARCHAR(200) DEFAULT NULL, asdsa VARCHAR(200) DEFAULT NULL, nssad VARCHAR(200) DEFAULT NULL ";
```

How I create it

Comment: What language are you using? What have you tried so far, and what specific problems are you encountering?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a C-style for loop & build a concatenated string. They look like this:

JavaScript:

```
var myArray = ['name', 'location', 'village', 'school', 'description', '...'];
var str = 'String val = "';
var max = myArray.length;

for (var i=0; i<max; i++) {
   str += myArray[i] + ' VARCHAR(200) DEFAULT NULL';
   if (i<max) {
      str += ',';
   }
}
```

Now make sure that you experiment by editing that code, as you use other array options + you have a 202 character max limit for location.

PHP would use this. See their [for loop](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php) examples:

```
for ($i=0; $i<max; $i++) {
   ...
}
```

So depending on the language, the for loop's syntax may vary. Good luck! :)